# Kernel function with a feature space equipped with an inner product that is not the dot product

Tags: kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

*Premise:*

> A function $K: \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is called
>   a kernel function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ if there exists a Hilbert space
>   $\mathcal{H}$ and a map $\phi: \mathbb R^d \to \mathcal{H}$ such that
>   for any $\mathbf x, \mathbf y\in \mathbb{R}^d$: \begin{equation}
>  \label{eq:kerdef} K(\mathbf x,\mathbf y) = \langle \phi(\mathbf x),
>  \phi(\mathbf y) \rangle_\mathcal{H}, \end{equation} where $
>  \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product.

I have recently noticed that under this definition $ \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ **is not necessary the standard inner product (dot product)**.

I have thought of the following example.
Consider the degree-two polynomial kernel on $\mathbb R^2$:
\begin{equation}
K(\mathbf x,\mathbf y) = (\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf y)^2.
\end{equation}
Then, the following is a valid feature map for this kernel:
\begin{equation}
\phi(\mathbf x) = (2\mathbf x_1 \mathbf x_1,~ 2\mathbf x_1 \mathbf x_2,~ 2\mathbf x_2 \mathbf x_1,~ 2\mathbf x_2 \mathbf x_2 ),
\end{equation}
considering the feature space $\mathcal H=\mathbb R^4$, with the custom inner product:
\begin{equation}
\langle\mathbf x, \mathbf y \rangle = \frac{\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf y}{4}.
\end{equation}

*Proof:*
\begin{align}
\langle \phi(\mathbf x), \phi(\mathbf y) \rangle_\mathcal{H} &= (2\mathbf x_1 \mathbf x_1,~ 2\mathbf x_1 \mathbf x_2,~ 2\mathbf x_2 \mathbf x_1,~ 2\mathbf x_2 \mathbf x_2 ) \cdot (2\mathbf y_1 \mathbf y_1,~ 2\mathbf y_1 \mathbf y_2,~ 2\mathbf y_2 \mathbf y_1,~ 2\mathbf y_2 \mathbf y_2 )/4\\
&= (\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y)^2 \\&= K(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)
\end{align}

*Question:*

Can you provide a less trivial example of kernel function, feature map and feature space, with an inner product that is not the dot product?

Comment: For complete real vector spaces, all inner products are dot products when a suitable basis is chosen, so there shouldn't exist any non-trivial examples.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Orthonormal_sequences.